# Unable to deploy war file on to Tomcat8 in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, deployment, web-deployment, tomcat8, devops

I'm doing a project as part of DevOps certification.

I need to build a pipeline which contains around 6 steps.

In the 5th step, I need to generate a .war file (which is successful).

In the last step, i need to deploy the war file which contains artifacts on to tomcat using Jenkins.

The project keeps failing. Is that something because of incorrect configuration. Here are the attached screenshots of build, post-build actions, and the console output of project.

**Build and post-build actions**
[image]
**console-output of the project**
[image]
Where am I doing it wrong.

Comment: looks like you're missing a `.jar` file of the same name of the target `.war` file, are you looking at the right place ?

Answer (score 0):

There's issue either while reading your dependencies from pom.xml file or there are some missing dependencies. The stack trace gives build failure in gameoflife-web module.

Try building the same module in Eclipse IDE and you'll find the same error there and you can solve this by adding proper dependencies.
This issue is not of Jenkins when the build is not successful, it will always fail.

Comment: Fixed this issue by simply executing shell command for copying .war file to /webapps directory

Comment: @Sukumar The build is not stable, there will be no use of copying to /webapps directory.

Comment: Not sure about that. But the app is working completely as expected after copying to webapps directory.

Comment: @Sukumar But this is not a good practice that you have build errors in your project especially in java.